# Problems with my Calendar App Project

Tags: java, android

So, I have this assignment at school where I have to make in Android Studio an app that manages daily tasks,basically a calendar, but the activities are saved in a server with JSON format. The problem is that I have a list of all activities in a day in a RecyclerView and I have to have a button for each activity that allows me to delete it from the server and I have no idea how can I do that, I mean, when I delete an activity i have to do it with its ID.
I currently have an app that works but i have to add that functionality, i have an Activity that has a recyclerView and shows the name of the task, the start and finish time and a button.I don't know if I can put the task ID in a hidden field so I can use that or is there a better way to do it.
I'm new with Android programming, so its kinda confusing.

This is the code that I use to get the JSON data.

```
 public class dayActivities extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private JsonManager json;
    ArrayList<Tarea> list;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    String url="http://186.16.12.200:3000/agenda1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_day_activities);


        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String date = b.getString("fecha");
        setTitle(getDate(date));
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());;

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        this.getData(date);


    }
    public void getData(String date){
        list=new ArrayList<Tarea>();

        JsonArrayRequest arrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + "?fecha=" + date,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            // The user does have repos, so let's loop through them all.
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    // For each repo, add a new line to our repo list.

                                    JSONObject jsonObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    Integer id = (Integer) jsonObj.get("id");
                                    String actividad = jsonObj.get("actividad").toString();
                                    String fecha = jsonObj.get("fecha").toString();
                                    String inicio = jsonObj.get("horaInicio").toString();
                                    String fin = jsonObj.get("horaFin").toString();

                                    list.add(new Tarea(id,actividad,fecha,inicio,fin));

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // If there is an error then output this to the logs.
                                    Log.e("Volley", "Invalid JSON Object.");
                                }

                            }
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new Adaptador(list));
                        } else {
                            // The user didn't have any repos.
                            Log.e("Volley", "Not found");
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        // Add the request we just defined to our request queue.
        // The request queue will automatically handle the request as soon as it can.
        requestQueue.add(arrReq);

    }
    public String getDate(String fecha){
        String meses[]={"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto,","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre"};
        return fecha.substring(6)+" de "+meses[Integer.parseInt(fecha.substring(4,6))-1]+" del "+fecha.substring(0,4);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. You can create a RestAPI which speaks with your Android client. If you don't need authentication it is not very difficult. If you provide some code as a starting point we can help you more.

Comment: I already have the part that makes the Json requests, i used Volley. I edited my post to add the code that I use to get the data and put it into the recyclerview. The problem is to make the delete request of an activity when I press the delete button on the recyclerview